# Permission denied to edit the file in sysroot which used sshfs

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, arm, sshfs

I set up the sysroot of odroid xu4 board (arm board) in macbook using sshfs through ssh. So I can see all the folders and files on my macbook. I just wondering if it should be able to edit those files in this sysroot (on my macbook).
Any suggestions will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix it by **sshfs -o idmap=user,follow_symlinks user@targethost:/ $SYSROOT**